# How to input multiple strings on one line in Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I want to know that how to read a line with multiple String words using Scanner class of JAva.

Comment: if so what would be a short example?

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific way to do that. Anyway you can provide comma separated strings as below example.

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str = in.nextLine();
    String[] strArr = str.split(",");
    for(String s: strArr){
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

write a method like this:

```
function String reader(Scanner s, int lines){
    String ret = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < lines; i++)
        ret += s.nextLine();
    return ret;
}
```

and use it like this:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
String threeLines = reader(s, 3);
```

It's just a for loop that loops and read multiple lines